# Compatible stand alone multi-touch display for Ubuntu?

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, multi-touch, touchscreen

I'm looking for a multi-touch monitor solution that i can connect to a workstation running Ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone know of a stand alone monitor I can use where touch actions would go over a usb connection like the dell touch monitors and windows 8?

Dell's tech support said their touch monitors like the P2314 are not supported on linux
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=859-BBBC

I did come across System76's sable touch but this doesn't work for me as it is more like a tablet with a keyboard. I need the monitor to be separate from the PC. Being able to connect two separate multi-touch monitors wouldn't hurt either.
https://system76.com/desktops/model/sabt2

Comment: I'll upvote any answer that includes you verified the monitor 's multi-touch capability worked against a known linux distro. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it a hardware recommendation request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW I have this monitor the Dell P2714T and I installed a copy of Ubuntu 14.04 and attached the usb connection to this monitor and the multi-touch worked like a charm. No need for any additional drivers!

http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=210-ABMB

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell P2314t touch screen monitor and am using a LePotato aml-s905x-cc board connected via usb and hdmi and had touch capability without any drivers needing to be installed. Currently uses Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop from libre